# Chrome DevTools: setting a breakpoint on document scroll change?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

Sometimes, in a large clientside webapp, it's necessary to identify which line of code has scrolled the document with a `scrollTo()` call (or if this is even the cause of the scroll*).

Is there any Chrome DevTools feature which will break JS execution on a window scroll? I'm imagining a feature similar to the DOM Breakpoints feature.

* Scrolling can also happen for other reasons, such as text input in an offscreen `<input>`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use a JavaScript event listener breakpoint. In the sources tab for Chrome developer tools, locate the "Event Listener Breakpoints" and then the "scroll" breakpoint is located under "Control".

Comment: didnt work for me :(. Added a breakpoint, but when manually scrolling (using the mousewheel) or when entering text in a textbox something is scrolling the window, but no breakpoint

Comment: @Mario Perhaps this will only break on javascript event listeners? I notice it works on this stackoverflow page: it breaks in what looks like jQuery's scroll handler.

Comment: exactly, I don't have events on the scroll, so that didnt cause to break @ certain point

Comment: 404 HTTP. Link not work

Answer (score 12):

The way I use it to override/proxy the `scroll` functions and set a `debugger` in the new function.

I run the following snippet in the console, with the hope one of the scroll functions will be called:

```
const proxyFn = fnName => {
  const oldFn = window[fnName];
  window[fnName] = (...args) => {
    debugger;
    oldFn(...args)
  }
}

Object.keys(window).filter(c => c.includes("scroll")).forEach(c => proxyFn(c))
// or, if you want to "catch" the "scrollTo" function
proxyFn("scrollTo")
```

Comment: This work well, but seems to work only if `window.scrollTo(...)` is called. What to do to catch it for other scrollable elements (e.g. any element being defined as "overflow: auto")?

Comment: @TXN You'd have to _guess_ what function can be called, if the scroll is triggered programmatically, and usually `scrollTo` is being used. You may want to use the element reference instead of `window` to proxy the scroll functions on a particular element.